# How to resolve Canonical ID's issue for GCM in IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have chosen GCM for push notification in ios and android app. I faced no problem in solving canonical issue for Android.

I am getting the proper response back but for ios. I am receiving the JSON as following for a single device I have 4 registration tokens for the same device in the database. The message is received 3 times for the same device. How can I resolve this?
Here is the Results array from the response:

```
{"message_id":"0:1442401536556937%1c3dd21f1c3dd21f"}
{"message_id":"0:1442401536556734%1c3dd21f1c3dd21f"},
{"message_id":"0:1442401536556938%1c3dd21f1c3dd21f"},
{"message_id":"0:1442401536556735%1c3dd21f1c3dd21f"}
```

Comment: You should delete the old registration tokens for the same device in your database, after you generate a new registration tokens every time.

Comment: @ztan Now there is only one device in the database. How will I detect which device registration token is correct and which should I delete for multiple devices?